# Contradicting relation between total power consumed and power consumed by each individual resistor in series and parallel configuration

Tags: electricity, power

In a given series configuration of n resistances of equal resistance r, I derived the relation bewteen total power and individual power consumption as follows:

P(Total) = I^2 * R

R= nr (equivalent resistance)

P(total) = n*I^2*r
         = n*p(individual)                          {p individual = I^2*r}

If the configuration is parallel:

P (total) = V^2/R
          = V^2 * n/r
          =n* p(individual)                        {p individual = V^2/r}

But this seems to imply that power consumed is the same for both.

Can someone point out where I went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They only look like they're consuming the same power because you're implicitly *using a different power source* in each case.

For example, let's first look at a **constant-voltage** source, which maintains a constant voltage drop $V$ across whatever load it's connected to, and allows the current to vary. Let $I_s$ be the current drawn by the series configuration, and let $I_p$ be the current drawn by the parallel configuration. The series configuration has an equivalent resistance of $nr$, so $I_s=\frac{V}{nr}$. In contrast, the parallel configuration has an equivalent resistance of $r/n$, so $I_p=\frac{nV}{r}$.

This means that the power consumed by the series configuration is $P_s=I_s^2(nr)=\frac{V^2}{nr}$, and the power consumed by the parallel configuration is $P_p=I^2_p(\frac{r}{n})=\frac{nV^2}{r}$. The power consumed by the **parallel** configuration is higher for a constant-voltage source.

In contrast, a **constant-current** source maintains a constant current $I$ through whatever load it's connected to, and allows the voltage drop to vary. Let $V_s$ be the voltage drop across the series configuration and $V_p$ be the voltage drop across the parallel configuration. We see, as before, that $V_s=Inr$ and $V_p=\frac{Ir}{n}$.

This means that the power consumed by the series configuration is $P_s=\frac{V_s^2}{nr}=I^2nr$ and the power consumed by the parallel configuration is $P_p=\frac{nV_p^2}{r}=\frac{I^2r}{n}$. The power consumed by the **series** configuration is higher for a constant-current source.

So which configuration consumes more power depends on what kind of power supply it's connected to. In your question, you compare the power consumed by series resistors *attached to a constant-voltage source* with the power consumed by parallel resistors *attached to a constant-current source*, which really aren't the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can point it out.

You went wrong in line seven of your question.

In both the parallel and serial case the total power consumed is indeed n times the power consumed by an individual resistor.

However, in the parallel case, each resistor takes the full voltage V. The power consumed by each resistor is VV/r so the total power is nVV/r.

If the resistors are in series the `voltage drops gradually over each of them, so an individual resistor sees only V/n volts. The power consumed by each resistor is VV/nnr. The total power consumed is nVV/nnr or VV/nr.

The power differs by a factor of nn.

Best wishes.